# How do I output the array's elements (on odd positions, that have an odd amount of even digits?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have 4 elements, in this order: 4 10 2546 and 100, 4 and 2546 are on odd positions, 4 has 1 even digit and 2546 has 3 even digits, so the output should be "4 2546", however my program only outputs "0 0", and I think it's because of the while loop, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, evenDigits = 0, r, x;

    cout << "How many elements?\n";
    cin >> n;

    int* v = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i=i+2){

        evenDigits = 0;
        x = v[i];

        while(x != 0){
            r = x % 10;
            if(r % 2 == 0)
                evenDigits++;
            x /= 10;
        }
        if(evenDigits % 2 == 1)
            cout << x << " ";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logic and execution. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. We don't debug other people's code on Stackoverflow, but with your debugger's help you can find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without needing any help

Comment: If you terminate a while loop by means other than break or return (or similar) the condition is false, i.e. in your case `x != 0` is false so `x == 0` is true. Btw. If you use `new` make sure to use `delete` somewhere. Put `delete[] v;` just before the return to free the memory you've allocated dynamically.

Comment: Your cout statement is wrong. your are outputting x instead of v[i]. So please write ````cout << v[i] << " ";````

Comment: @ArminMontigny could you put your answer as and actual answer instead of a comment so i can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small typo.

In the cout statement you your showing the value of x, which has been made 0 by the divisions.

You need to show the original valeu, stored in v[i].

So, please modify you cout statement to:

```
cout << v[i] << " ";
```